Greenplum's distribution transaction is not written on segment's wal file
If some gp_segment(node) does not have distribution transaction data, then the wal file of this gp_segment does not have any information about this transaction.
Do you know may be some option, that allows to add some information this transaction, exists? For example, only empty transaction with gid.
I need collect all data of some global transaction from all gp segments, but I cannot define that all data with same gid is collected for some global transaction.
Thank you.
